# How to make a basic connection to Github in Sourcetree

Tags: authentication, github, passwords, atlassian-sourcetree

When trying to clone a repo from Github in SourceTree, it keeps telling me the repo URL is invalid, when I've copy/pasted it directly from the repo's Github page.

I'm using HTTPS and trying to make a Basic connection in SourceTree

Github connection attempt:

[image: Github connection attempt]

I'm sure I'm entering my username and github password correctly, but it's saying it cannot connect?

I would expect my Github username and password to make the connection work, but it appears not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason why SourceTree does accept your GitHub password, and is "looking for a PAT -- Personal Access Token --, is that, as mentioned in "[Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)":

> A personal access token is required to authenticate to GitHub when you're using [two-factor authentication](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-two-factor-authentication).

If you have 2FA, you need a PAT as a password.

Answer (score 4):

So the issue was I was giving it my actual Github account password, and what it is looking for is a Personal Access Token created for my account.

To do this I went to my github account page Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens and created a new token.  Using that token in the 'password' section of the SourceTree account connection panel I was able to connect!